# C# check value in set accessor

Tags: c#, set, accessor

How will be better in optimization goals?

```
public SpeedGraphModel SpeedGraphModel
{
    get { return _speedGraphModel; }
    set { 
            if (_speedGraphModel == value)
                return;

            _speedGraphModel = value; 
        }
}
```

or

```
public SpeedGraphModel SpeedGraphModel
{
    get { return _speedGraphModel; }
    set { _speedGraphModel = value; }
}
```

I think for `string` type will be better without checking, but for other types?

Comment: Do you really think that this makes any difference _performance wise_?

Comment: Are you sure you're not faling victim to [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)?

Comment: Why would you even want code like this? This disrupts the readability. You can do `public SpeedGraphModel SpeedGraphModel { get; set; }`. It is highly unlikely that this could ever make a difference in performance with modern day hardware.

Comment: Unless you're really into low level implementation details (which I doubt you're), this is the kind of mistakes beginners make. I have been there and I have learned from it, to never ever worry about it. I dont know how to convince you but you should always just assign it (your second approach). 1 year from now when you look into this question you will feel stupid.

Comment: May be in the rarest of case if `SpeedGraphModel` is 500 byte struct then yes copying will have a noticeable penalty but having a struct that large is wrong thing to do in the first place, moreover the conditional check for such a large struct most probably will involve time consuming equality operation which can anyway negate the advantage of not copying. As always if it all this is worrying you, rethink about the design and if you think your design is sound then measure it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Adding another condition check instead of setting the variable value, even if it equal is redundant.

**The best case** if they are equal you will make 1 operation (condition).
**The worst case** you will make 2 operations (condition + assignment).

Instead of setting the variable **no matter what**. => 1 operation.

Answer (score 0):

Such checking is usually used when you call some logic on the setting value (not only just set it). For instance, in desktop (WPF/WinForms) or mobile (Xamarin) you can implement your own property that behavior will be similar to the Dependency Property and call the `OnPropertyChanged()` method inside it. It can be used for refreshing items of the view after their updating etc. In this way, even if you set the same value to your item and then call `OnPropertyChanged()` it will update part of the view that can affect the performance, so you would like to make an additional check here.

If you just have a usual property, the only responsibility of which is to set value inside the private field without any logic behind, you don’t need an additional checking as it redundant and won’t increase your performance.